# HTML5 audio start over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, browser

Having

```
var audio = new Audio("click.ogg")
```

I play the click sound when needed by

```
audio.play()
```

However, sometimes user is so fast that a browser does not play the audio at all (probably when still playing a previous `play` request). Is this issue related to **preload**?

How can I force a browser to stop playing and start over? There is no `stop`, just `pause` in HTML5 audio component, correct? What workaround can be used here?

---

**Update** - Additional note:

I have multiple checkbox-like `div` elements with a `touchend` event. When such event is triggered, the elements visually change, a sound is played and an internal variable is set accordingly. If user tap on these elements slowly, everything works nicely. If tap fast, the sound is often completely skipped...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just reset the audio `currentTime` and ensure it's playing using the `play()` method. Checking if the audio is playing is not necessary as subsequent `play()` invocations will not do anything.

```
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
```

Comment: Great solution. Faster then excepted answer. Ty

Comment: @MaciejBukowski Chrome 71.

Answer (score 9):

This is the code I've been using and it's working for me:

```
            if(audioSupport.duration > 0 && !audioSupport.paused){

                //already playing
                audioSupport.pause();
                audioSupport.currentTime = 0;
                audioSupport.play();

            }else{

                //not playing

                audioSupport.play();    

            }
```

Comment: I don't think it's even necessary to check if it's already playing.  Just do this...
audioSupport.pause(); audioSupport.currentTime = 0; audioSupport.play();

Comment: And I also dont think it necessary to pause.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that on Firefox, playing a sound again and again really fast (like a short ticking sound) will skip beats often. The best solution I got was to simply call `cloneNode` and play each sound that way. Its not perfect (compared to Chrome where it sounds flawless):

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
setInterval(function() {
    audio.cloneNode().play();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way i found how to play a short sound very quickly (so quick that the 2nd sound starts before the first ends) is to actually load 5 or 10 and if you have to play again but are already playing, just go to the next, which is not playing:

```
    var soundEls = [];//load 10 audios instead of 1
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        var soundEl = document.createElement('audio');
        soundEl.src = url;
        soundEl.preload = 'auto';
        $(this._soundEl).append(soundEl);
        soundEls.push(soundEl);
    }

    var soundElIndex = 0;

    return {play:function(){
        var soundEl = soundEls[soundElIndex];

        if(soundEl.duration > 0 && !soundEl.paused){

            //already playing, switch to next soundEl
            soundElIndex++;
            if(!soundEls[soundElIndex]) soundElIndex=0;
            soundEls[soundElIndex].play();

        }else{

            //not playing
            soundEl.play();    

        }

    }};
```

Result of this is you can actually play the same sound over itself.

Probably not the right way to do it though.